# how to join 2 data stream with different meta data?

Tags: stream, bigdata, pentaho

I have two stream with different meta-data or data-struct, one group defination table which indicate User group  by user name, language, gender, the range of user age was describe by 2 fields, “age_start”, “age_end”(all these group indicator can change some day later, even add new colnum to indicate different user group, so I need to be able to implement the workflow dynamically),

[image]

second table is user info table, as below

[image]

How can I using pentaho to find out specific user_id belong to which group(by gender, language, age scope)

Can javascript have two heterogeneous data stream as input to caculate the result, or we have other more smart and straight forward way to doing similar work

Thanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can using Join Rows (cartesian product) to achieve you requirement. set "age <= age_end and age >= age_start" as condition.

Comment: another option would be using the stream lookup step to retrieve the first hit on the secondary stream. Depending on whether you want all matching records or just the first one, these are probably the two best options.

Comment: stream may work for one field, but difficult to work for two field of above case, I think, if it can, please specify the detail steps, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could use a javascript step to map an age to an age group, something like:

if (age>=0 and age<=17.... etc.) then age_group = AGE_GROUP_ID

You could assign id's do the age groups (can't see if there's already an id there) and then use a stream lookup step to get the data. Javascript steps don't accept multiple input streams. In your case it's better to use 2 separate steps to achieve what you're trying to do.

Of course, this is just one way, and bear in mind that javascript steps can be quite slow depending on the amount of data you're processing. But again, I don't know this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use javascript? Since the data already is in tables why don't you use the database join step?

Another option is to read the two tables using table inputs and join the streams. Then you could use a stream look up. This will cache all the data resulting in very fast lookups.